# Computing the elements of many 4 x 4 matrices using Table

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

```
ClearAll
k1 = {0.01, 1, 2, 6, 10, 25, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1500, 
  4000, 1*^3, 5*^4, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12}
k2 = {0.01, 1, 2, 6, 10, 25, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1500, 
  4000, 1*^3, 5*^4, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12}
(*Stiffness matrix*)
K = {{555432.324664115` + 2.6746737724106636`*^-8 *k1[[i]] + 
    2090.2057564938596` *k2[[j]], 
   1.1094150869528523`*^6 + 0.017386104625746142` *k1[[i]] + 
    0.0006631240389023547` *k2[[j]], 
   2.845834229841793` + 5.32364177542491`*^-8 *k1[[i]] + 
    0.00012854890426959917` *k2[[j]], 
   121725.48067658773` - 0.013197174818993334` *k1[[i]] + 
    3689.266938246801` *k2[[j]]}, {1.1094150869528523`*^6 + 
    0.017386104625746142` *k1[[i]] + 0.0006631240389023547` *k2[[j]], 
   3.003138830419737`*^6 + 11301.439344692557` *k1[[i]] + 
    2.1037808818773268`*^-10 *k2[[j]], -5.267990413208868` + 
    0.034605114781571716` *k1[[i]] + 
    4.078252503653899`*^-11 *k2[[j]], -283044.8148469298` - 
    8578.521408256873` *k1[[i]] + 
    0.001170430989905433` *k2[[j]]}, {2.845834229841793` + 
    5.32364177542491`*^-8 *k1[[i]] + 
    0.00012854890426959917` *k2[[j]], -5.267990413208868` + 
    0.034605114781571716` *k1[[i]] + 
    4.0782525036538995`*^-11 *k2[[j]], 
   3.424398770404721`*^7 + 1.0596119065206824`*^-7 *k1[[i]] + 
    7.905834503409627`*^-12 *k2[[j]], 
   1.4481184017097415` - 0.026267514157682283` *k1[[i]] + 
    0.00022689212341717058` *k2[[j]]}, {121725.48067658773` - 
    0.013197174818993334` *k1[[i]] + 
    3689.2669382468007` *k2[[j]], -283044.8148469298` - 
    8578.521408256873` *k1[[i]] + 0.001170430989905433` *k2[[j]], 
   1.4481184017097415` - 0.026267514157682286` *k1[[i]] + 
    0.0002268921234171706` *k2[[j]], 
   422863.23538959975` + 6511.651065621275` *k1[[i]] + 
    6511.651065621256` *k2[[j]]}}
K // MatrixForm
(*Mass Matrix*)
M = {{8.269850749287782`, -0.945119516969959`, 
   0.000028214890123714687`, 
   15.068107915799132`}, {-0.945119516969959`, 44.71384637610789`, 
   0.00005496200218081672`, -35.03739440720928`}, \
{0.000028214890123714687`, 0.00005496200218081672`, 
   52.33337314007661`, -0.000030371323002403867`}, \
{15.068107915799132`, -35.03739440720928`, -0.000030371323002403867`, 
   52.345419186800605`}}
M // MatrixForm
g1 = Do[K, {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
g2 = Table[K, {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
```

I have a stiffness matrix which is a having a dependency on different values of k1 and k2. And i want to construct stiffness matrix **K** for all values of k1 and k2 .And i want to do eigen value analysis on stiffness matrix **K** and mass matrix **M**.I used **TABLE** to construct stiffness matrix for different values of k1 and k2 but failed , same goes with **DO** also.want to where i am doing mistake?

Comment: You _can_ do it with `Table`. Please, have a deep look into the documentation page of `Table`.

Comment: Btw.: Your "use" of `ClearAll` is meaningless (have a look at its documentation page) and using `K` as a variable should be avoided since it is a built-in symbol. Moreover: It is not clear 1) which size the stiffness matrix is supposed to have and 2) what the precise formulas for its entries should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k1 = {0.01, 1, 2, 6, 10, 25, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1500, 
      4000, 1*^3, 5*^4, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
k2 = {0.01, 1, 2, 6, 10, 25, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1500, 
      4000, 1*^3, 5*^4, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
```

I take it you want 400 4 x 4 arrays. To get them, first define `K` as a function of two indices.

```
Clear[K]
K[i_, j_] := 
  {{555432.324664115` + 2.6746737724106636`*^-8*k1[[i]] + 2090.2057564938596`*k2[[j]], 
    1.1094150869528523`*^6 + 0.017386104625746142`*k1[[i]] + 0.0006631240389023547`*k2[[j]], 
    2.845834229841793` + 5.32364177542491`*^-8*k1[[i]] + 0.00012854890426959917`*k2[[j]], 
    121725.48067658773` - 0.013197174818993334`*k1[[i]] + 3689.266938246801`*k2[[j]]}, 
   {1.1094150869528523`*^6 + 0.017386104625746142`*k1[[i]] + 0.0006631240389023547`*k2[[j]], 
    3.003138830419737`*^6 + 11301.439344692557`*k1[[i]] + 2.1037808818773268`*^-10*k2[[j]], 
    -5.267990413208868` + 0.034605114781571716`*k1[[i]] + 4.078252503653899`*^-11*k2[[j]], 
    -283044.8148469298` - 8578.521408256873`*k1[[i]] + 0.001170430989905433`*k2[[j]]}, 
   {2.845834229841793` + 5.32364177542491`*^-8*k1[[i]] + 0.00012854890426959917`*k2[[j]], 
    -5.267990413208868` + 0.034605114781571716`*k1[[i]] + 4.0782525036538995`*^-11*k2[[j]], 
    3.424398770404721`*^7 + 1.0596119065206824`*^-7*k1[[i]] + 7.905834503409627`*^-12*k2[[j]], 
    1.4481184017097415` - 0.026267514157682283`*k1[[i]] + 0.00022689212341717058`*k2[[j]]}, 
   {121725.48067658773` - 0.013197174818993334`*k1[[i]] + 3689.2669382468007`*k2[[j]], 
    -283044.8148469298` - 8578.521408256873`*k1[[i]] + 0.001170430989905433`*k2[[j]], 
    1.4481184017097415` - 0.026267514157682286`*k1[[i]] + 0.0002268921234171706`*k2[[j]], 
    422863.23538959975` + 6511.651065621275`*k1[[i]] + 6511.651065621256`*k2[[j]]}}
```

Then compute

```
K400 = ArrayReshape[Table[K[i, j], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], {400, 4, 4}];
```

This produces 400 4 x 4 matches, each evaluated with different pair from the Cartesian product of `k1` and `k2`. That is

```
 Dimensions[K400]
```

> `{400, 4, 4}`

Here is a random sample of four matrices from  `K400`.

```
SeedRandom[42]; Column[MatrixForm /@ RandomSample[K400, 4]]
```

[image: sample]

Comment: But , sir can we do operations such as eigen value analysis on those matrix generated inside that table?

Comment: @vijay, just do something like `Eigensystem[K400[[20]]]` if you want the eigensystem of the 20th matrix in `K400`. If you need all of them, just do `Eigensystem /@ K400`.

Comment: Thnaks alot . I got it

Comment: One last query.I used something like Eigensystem[{K400,M}]. where the mass matrix M is having a size of 4*4. I know the size of K400 is 400*4*4.My question is how to carry out the generalized eigen value between each matrix of K400 and M and how to extract lowest natural frequency. Because Eigensystem[{A,B},n] gives first n eigen values. if i make n=1 it gives highest eigen value. Thank you

Comment: @vijay. Are you asking how to find the index of the matrix in K400 that has the lowest eigenvalue?

Comment: No its like I have another  matrix M, for  example  k400[[1,1]]  be my 4*4 matrix, then i want to compute  Eigenvalues[{K400[[1,1]],M}]. How to do this for all 4*4  matrix contained in K400? And i am interested in lowest natural frequency.

Comment: S = Table[K[i, j], {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
Dimensions[S];
Dimensions[K400];
val = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2, 1, 4}];
fn = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2, 1, 4}];
Eigenvalues[{S[[1, 1]], M}]
For[i = 1; j = 1, i < 3; j < 3, i++; j++, 
 val[[i, j]] = Eigenvalues[{S[[i, j]], M}]; 
 fn[[i, j]] = Sqrt[val[[i, j]]]/(2*Pi)]

Comment: This is my attempt , but i am failing

Comment: Try `evals[m_] = (Eigenvalues[{#, m}] &) /@ K400; ` With this definition, evals[M]m where `M` is a 4 x 4 matrix, will give a list of the 400 lists each of which contains the four eigenvalues of one of matrices of K400.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. How can I improve this question so that it would help people stuck in this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
kK = {{{555432.324664115`, 2.6746737724106636`*^-8, 2090.2057564938596`}, 
  {1.1094150869528523`*^6, 0.017386104625746142`,  0.0006631240389023547`},
  {2.845834229841793`, 5.32364177542491`*^-8,   0.00012854890426959917`}, 
  {121725.48067658773`,   -0.013197174818993334`, 3689.266938246801`}}, 
 {{1.1094150869528523`*^6,  0.017386104625746142`,  0.0006631240389023547`}, 
  {3.003138830419737`*^6, 11301.439344692557`, 2.1037808818773268`*^-10}, 
  {-5.267990413208868`,  0.034605114781571716`,  4.078252503653899`*^-11},
  {-283044.8148469298`,  -8578.521408256873`, 0.001170430989905433`}}, 
 {{2.845834229841793`,  5.32364177542491`*^-8, 0.00012854890426959917`}, 
  {-5.267990413208868`, 0.034605114781571716`,  4.0782525036538995`*^-11}, 
  {3.424398770404721`*^7, 1.0596119065206824`*^-7, 7.905834503409627`*^-12}, 
  {1.4481184017097415`,  -0.026267514157682283`,  0.00022689212341717058`}}, 
 {{121725.48067658773`, -0.013197174818993334`, 3689.2669382468007`}, 
  {-283044.8148469298`, -8578.521408256873`, 0.001170430989905433`}, 
  {1.4481184017097415`, -0.026267514157682286`, 0.0002268921234171706`}, 
  {422863.23538959975`,  6511.651065621275`, 6511.651065621256`}}};

k1 = {0.01, 1, 2, 6, 10, 25, 75, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1500, 
   4000, 1*^3, 5*^4, 1*^6, 1*^8, 1*^12};
```

Taking the `Dot` product of the matrix `kK` with triples constructed using `k1` gives the desired result:

```
m400 = kK.# & /@ Tuples[{{1}, k1, k1}];
```

This result matches the output from m_goldberg's answer:

```
m400 == K400
```

> True

**Note:** The matrix `kK`can be obtained from OP's code using

```
ClearAll[k1, k2]
kK = Quiet @  (paste RHS of K here ) /. {Plus -> List, Times -> (# &)}
```

If you ***have to*** use `Table` you can do

```
m400b = Table[kK.i, {i, Tuples[{{1}, k1, k1}]}];
m400b == m400
```

> True